# How to install Django on shared hosting server with Plesk?

Tags: python, django, shared-hosting, plesk

My question is: how can I install DJANGO on a shared hosting account?

My hosting supports PYTHON 2.4. After copying the files to the ftp server, what is the next step? On Django site it says you need to to this:

```
tar xzvf Django-1.3.tar.gz
cd Django-1.3
sudo python setup.py install
```

But I dont see any command shell on my plesk account admin page. Now, there is an option on my hosting provider that gives what they call *`"SSH chrooted shell access with a limited command set"`* for €60 euros more.

Do I need to get that shell access upgrade for Django/PYTHON development?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a "django ready" hoster <strike>(eg google apps)</strike>!

here's an collection of links
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoFriendlyWebHosts

Comment: google app engine is not a "django ready" hoster. You need tweaks to make it work with BigTable.

Answer (score 4):

They probably wouldn't give you root access with your SSH access anyway. You can "install" a python library without root access by just copying it into the same directory as your application. Extract the contents of Django-1.3.tar.gz on your computer (not the shared server), find the folder inside named "django" and upload this to the ftp server in the folder containing your Django project.

Comment: Well, I have the root access to the device. Which one is a better way to run the Django app. Running it as described here(https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5910431-django-python-support) as a passenger? Or just configure it to run alongside the Plesk? The trouble is the documentation is written for Pytho2.x and Django1.x. Before you ask there is a WordPress app that uses Plesk. So Plesk is not redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I have been wondering the same thing. Thinking it would be easier to simply install Django on local machine (if you’re the only developer). For quick and easy setup, use Bitnami Django. If there are others working with you or you needed remote access, can open port to your local machine to make it accessible via the Internet (e.g. noip.com). If project is getting big, then it would be worth investing your time setting up or finding a proper host.